# Aniara Spear - One of many sent to destroy the Earth?

Tags: aliens, aniara

In *Aniara* (2019), the large metal Spear was made of an "unknown" material, so if we take this to mean "Alien" in origin and open the possibility that this Spear may have only been one of many launched on that trajectory, then this could have been part of a group of "Planet Killer" objects intended for the Earth.

This one missed and ended up on the same path as the Aniara, while the assumption being others made contact with the Earth. Shattered tectonic plates and the subsequent volcanic destabilization of the Earth would have easily "finished off" what was left of the Earth (just a massively larger version of the Cobra orbital satellite weapon from the *G.I. Joe* franchise).

So the Aliens would have originated from the general vector of where?

The Aniara took a "right" following their mishap with the engine, so what would be "to the left"?